# WebRTC peer iceconnectionstatechange and connectionstatechange dont fire "closed" event from Chrome 80

Tags: webrtc, chromium, rtcpeerconnection

WebRTC iceconnectionstatechange and connectionstatechange dont fire "closed" event in Chrome 80. Does anyone have any workaround to detect the connectionstatechange when peer is closed? It doesnot fire even in plan-b

Answer (score 1):

They don't fire when calling pc.close() anymore. See
  https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1023736

If your JS code calls pc.close() you surely have detected that the other side went away somehow.

Comment: Are pc.close() and iceconnectionstate in sync? If I close a peer and access its icestate in the next line, will the iceconnectionstate be in the state closed? How do I get a proper acknowledgement?

Comment: close isn't something that is acknowledged in any way. But according to https://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#dom-rtcpeerconnection-close it is a synchronous operation.
In general you call close and dispose the peerconnection without further thinking.

Comment: Thanks for your input. our reconnection mechanism was based on the ice closed state, so basically this has broke the reconnection completely.